# AWS Lambda function + SNS send email of event status

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns

I am new to AWS SNS and was looking for some suggestions to understand the steps to set up email notifications for status of my AWS LAMDA function
I am trying to use this to setup, but would appreciate any other tutorial/document of steps -
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-cloudwatch-sns-notifications.html